# Test useSelector value change post-mount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a React component which displays a message when a user goes offline and then another message when the user goes back online. The online/offline status is handled by another part of the codebase and the values are stored on the Redux store.

The component uses the `useSelector` hook to get the offline status like this:

```
const isOffline = useSelector(deviceSelectors.isOffline);
```

and I am using a `useEffect` hook in order to update the status and display the different DOM like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOffline) {
      setUserHasBeenOffline(true);

      if (userWentOnline) {
        setUserWentOnline(false);
      }
    }

    if (userHasBeenOffline && !isOffline) {
      setUserWentOnline(true);
      setUserHasBeenOffline(false);
    }
  }, [isOffline, userHasBeenOffline, userWentOnline]);
```

Now I am trying to test the codepath when the user has been offline and then they come back online.

I've got a perfectly working test like this for the initial codepath:

```
  const setupMount = setupWithProvider({
    render: () => <NetworkStatus />,
    [[deviceSelectors.isOffline, false]],
    initialState: {
      device: {
        offline: false,
      },
    },
  });

  it('should render the network status alert for when the user has gone offline', () => {
    const { wrapper } = setupMount({
      selectors: [[deviceSelectors.isOffline, true]],
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('...').exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

My question is, how can I update the selector's value after mount? It doesn't seem that this information is easily accessible on the internet, as I've looked a lot.

What I've tried:

1. I've tried destructuring `dispatch` too and dispatch the action I need to update the selector's return value indirectly, but `setupWithProvider`'s `dispatch` is a mock function. And I couldn't find a working way with this.
2. I checked if the property was available to the wrapper as a prop to update it, but it was not.